# can't get image and text to align with CSS/flexbox under the navbar

Tags: html, css, display, text-alignment, text-align

I've been trying to align text to the right of an image but no matter what I do -- when the text line gets to be too long -- it keeps showing up right underneath the image instead of continuing onto the next line next to the image. I've tried to add a display inline for the text but it doesn't change a thing. I've also attempted to float the image to the left but it ends up cutting my image in half.

```
p {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 30px;
    justify-content: right;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    padding-left: 90px;
    opacity: 0.55;
    height: auto;
   
}

div {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #361833;
    min-height: 40vh;
}
```

The HTML file :

```
<div>
<div>
  <br>
  <img src='../../assets/img/image0.jpeg' alt="wj" width="500"/>
  <p>some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here shdfklshjfsldfhskdjfzf</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated as I'm pretty new to CSS! Thanks!

Comment: @RayeesAC doesn't change anything :/

Comment: you can use `word-break:break-word;` to align text next line.

Comment: you mentioned flex but youre not using it just add display flex;

Answer (score 2):

try this instead using `flex property` instead of `float`.

Also add to p tag `word-break:break-word;` to align next line

Result desktop view:

[image]

Mobile view:

[image]

```css
p {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 30px;
    justify-content: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break:break-word
}

img {
    padding-left: 90px;
    opacity: 0.55;
    height: auto;

}

.nav {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #361833;
    min-height: 40vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .nav {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="nav">
    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/amhjm.png' alt="wj" width="500"/>
    <p>some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here shdfklshjfsldfhskdjfzf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! this works for the most part. the only issue is it seems to squish the image when the length of the line gets to be too long -- any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this problem by setting a width to my text!

Comment: I would strongly recommend still having a good look at Rayees CSS code, as this is one of the best , if not the best, ways to do that to include responsiveness.

Comment: @LaurentC rayees's css code squishes the image when the text gets too long and that isn't my aim

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen I can use? thank yhou

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been up for a while, but I've simplified this so the image doesn't get squished. Not sure why that was a viable solution anyway.

```css
header {
  background-color: #361833;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav p {
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav">
    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/amhjm.png' alt="wj"/>
    <p>some loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text here shdfklshjfsldfhskdjfzf</p>
  </div>
</header>
```